# Filter out pins having same clock attribute

Tags: tcl, filtering, vlsi, cadence, searchfiltercollection

Getting all fanin to the endpoint

```
get_pins [all_fanin -to <end_point>/d -flat -startpoints_only]
```

Above will give list of clocks pins coming to the endpoint.

Now If I want to filter out clock pins having clocks attribute as "clock_name1*", I am using below. This is giving error

```
filter_collection [get_pins [all_fanin -to <endpoint>/d -flat -startpoints_only]] "clocks=~clock_name1*"


Error: Type mismatch between '@clocks' and '"clock_name1"'. (FLT-006)
Error: while parsing filter expression: 
        at 'clocks==clock_name1
            ________^' (FLT-003)
```

clocks is a collection while clock name is string.  Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Does this question refer to Cadence EDA tools?  If so, please add a suitable tag for this, otherwise it's not going to be seen by people with knowledge of that area.

Comment: For those of us without specific experience with the Cadence tool suite, how would you get that information for a *single* clock pin?

Comment: get_attr [get_pins <clock pins>]  clocks